# How to properly include Armadillo in CLion (without having false errors)?

Tags: c++, armadillo, clion

When I use the header-only [Armadillo C++ library](http://arma.sourceforge.net/) in [CLion](https://www.jetbrains.com/clion/), the IDE indicates (highlights) multiple (false) errors in the code, however the usage of Armadillo is valid and the code builds and runs without any errors.

For example, in a very simple Armadillo test project, the IDE indicates 3 errors, as written in the comments:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "armadillo"

using namespace std;
using namespace arma;

int main() {
    cout << "Armadillo version: " << arma_version::as_string() << endl;
    // Returns 5.0.1 (Ankle Biter)

    mat A(2,3);  // Error: Too many arguments, expected 0
    A.fill(99);
    A(1,2) += 101.0;  // Error: Called object is not a function
    A.print("A = ");
    A.set_size(4,5); // Error: Too many arguments, expected 1
    A.fill(77);
    A.print("A = ");

    return 0;
}
```

Since Armadillo is header-only, I did not modify the default `CMakeLists.txt` file, only included the main header in main.cpp and copied `armadillo_bits` to the project directory.

I've tried to configure Armadillo with CMake, but on Windows it seems Armadillo's bundled CMakeLists.txt just copies the includes and creates a config.hpp in my working dir.

Is there a way to index symbols in header-only libraries?

CLion version is 1.0 (141.353), Armadillo version is 5.0.1.
My platform is Windows 8.1 x64, and I'm using MinGW v64 4.9.2 (x86_64-4.9.2-win32-seh-rt_v4-rev2)

[The CLion project is available in this repository](https://github.com/Gyebro/clion-projects).

Thanks to anyone trying to investigate this issue.

Comment: There are a few other instances of correct and compiling code showing errors in clion. Boost::assign::list_of often gives similar errors. It seems it's a template-understanding problem with the way clion uses clang.

Comment: I should mention: Armadillo isn't header-only, that's Eigen. You've got to link with ${ARMADILLO_LIBRARIES} and likely against 'blas' and 'lapack' to use any operations without linker errors. (This still won't fix this issue)

Comment: Thanks Tim! I might check the code with a standalone Clang analyzer.