# CLion syntax error issues with opencv/armadillo

Tags: syntax-highlighting, clion

I am using CLion to do C++ development on Mac OS. It's a great IDE with many cool features, but I find the syntax error highlighting feature doesn't work well with matrix libraries like armadillo/opencv.

I installed the libraries via `brew`, and I am using Apple `clang` toolchain. However, CLion is showing too many distracting syntax errors incorrectly, even though the program compiles perfectly fine with `cmake`. Is there a way to solve this issue?

Below is a screenshot of the one of the "errors":
[image: clion-opencv-error]

It's a perfectly ok opencv `mat` constructor with `MatExpr`, but somehow CLion doesn't find the right function defintion.

I can provide more details if needed. If nothing else works, I think a way to quickly toggle showing/hiding the errors would work for me as well, but I haven't figured that out yet either.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm having the same problem, it seems the false errors are related to clang. (Even asked a question a year ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29899738/how-to-properly-include-armadillo-in-clion-without-having-false-errors)

Comment: @Gyebro Are you able to workaround the issue by using say HomeBrew gcc then? I tried setting "Preferences => Toolchains => CMake" to `/usr/local/bin/cmake` but it didn't work.

Comment: It seems they have a task open for more than 3 years now: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/OC-7180 Hope they can fix this issue soon.